# SQL Server : zero values with COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table @MemberAttribute

```
MemberID AttributeID AttributeValue
1            1         False 
1            2         True 
2            1         False
2            2         True 
3            1         False
3            2         False
```

I want to group by attributeID and get count of attributes whose value is True. But when attributetype is false for a particular attribute there I want it to display 0. Right now the attributeID with all false vallues just doesn't show up.
Here is the sql query

```
SELECT MA.AttributeID, GA.Name,
--COUNT(isNull(MA.AttributeID,0)) as AttributCount,
CASE WHEN COUNT(MA.AttributeID) > 0 THEN COUNT(MA.AttributeID) Else 0 END AS 'AttributCount'
--CASE WHEN COUNT(MA.AttributeID) < 0 THEN 0 Else COUNT(MA.AttributeID) END AS 'TOTAL Attributes'
from GroupAttribute GA
inner join   @MemberAttribute MA on GA.GroupAttributeID = MA.AttributeID
WHERE MA.AttributeValue = 'True'
GROUP BY MA.AttributeID,GA.Name
```

FOR AttributeID = 1 all the values are = False... so the result is like this

```
AttributeID      Name      AttributeCount <br/>
2                Attr2        2 <br/>
```

I want

```
1                 Attr1      0  <br/>
```

too in the result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some wriggling, I came up with this beauty containing no `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT GA.GroupAttributeID AS AttributeID, GA.Name, 
       COUNT(MA.AttributeID) AS AttributeCount
FROM GroupAttribute AS GA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @MemberAttribute AS MA 
  ON GA.GroupAttributeID = MA.AttributeID AND MA.AttributeValue = 'True'
GROUP BY GA.GroupAttributeID, GA.Name
```

This takes advantage of the fact that if there are no 'True' values for a particular `AttributeID`, the `MA.AttributeID` resulting from the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will be `NULL`. The `NULL` value passed into `COUNT()` will lead to an `AttributeCount` of zero. The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` also ensures that a row will be present in the result set for `AttributeID` rows with zero counts.

The assumption with this query is that all group attributes are represented in the `@MemberAttribute` table variable. If not, there will be rows with zero counts representing those group attributes that are absent. If this is undesirable, a `WHERE` clause can be added to filter them out, complicating this query. Will's solution(s) would be far more practical if this is the case.

The execution plan compares well with Will's first solution, containing one less (Compute Scalar) step. It does use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` vs an `INNER JOIN`, however, making the two methods practically identical for this simple example. It would be interesting to see how the two solutions scale if table variable is converted to a fairly large table, instead.

Will's actual plan for his solution involving `COUNT()`:

[image]

My actual plan:

[image]

Comment: Not voting down, but this seems hugely overcomplex for the question asked. Are you seriously suggesting this as a viable alternative (along with the additional overhead of an added index) for the question that was asked here?

Comment: I agree, this is overly complex for the question asked. However, I am just showing an alternative if the solution is extrapolated to a real world problem involving more than a table variable with a few values... Also, it's an alternative with no CASE...

Comment: Ah, got it. So if I ask how to add 1 + 1, instead of explaining how to do that you want to explain the circuitry for a reverse Polish notation calculator in case I need it in the future?

Comment: @Ken, lol! You made me work hard on simplifying. Now, check out my improved solution, avoiding CASE and not even having a WHERE clause. I am interested in what you think of it :) .

Comment: @Michael ..sorry forgot to mark it as an answer... If possible can u explain why moving the condition  MA.AttributeValue = 'True'
from where clause to LEFT join makes such a big difference...  If I put this condition back in Where clause it doesnt give me the desired sol..it is the same result i was getting previously... but just moving that statement to the left join makes a big difference...can u explain it?

Comment: @Michael...forgot to add that your assumption (with this query is that all group attributes are represented in the @MemberAttribute table variable) will always be true in my case ... so need to add the statement in the WHERE clause.... However, I am still awaiting for some explanation on my previous comment

Comment: @Shazia, the reason lies in the fact that a WHERE clause would strip out rows with 'False' values, eliminating them completely from not just the count, but the result set as well. You don't want to eliminate them completely (just not count them) and this is what the LEFT OUTER JOIN does, instead of eliminating them, it presents them with a NULL @MemberAttribute.AttributeID, so that they can still be presented and counted (as zero). I hope this is a better explanation.

Comment: @Michael: :) Much better. The SHOW PLAN inclusion is also very nice. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this - note that the 1 in `...THEN 1 ELSE ...` is an arbitrary non-NULL value - it could be 'fred' or 12345 - that it's not NULL is the important part.

```
SELECT MA.AttributeID, GA.Name,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MA.AttributeValue = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'AttributeCount'
from GroupAttribute GA
inner join   @MemberAttribute MA on GA.GroupAttributeID = MA.AttributeID
GROUP BY MA.AttributeID,GA.Name
```

...somewhat more intuitively (thanks Ken) - and note that here the 1 and 0 are important...

```
SELECT MA.AttributeID, GA.Name,
SUM(CASE WHEN MA.AttributeValue = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'AttributeCount'
from GroupAttribute GA
inner join   @MemberAttribute MA on GA.GroupAttributeID = MA.AttributeID
GROUP BY MA.AttributeID,GA.Name
```

Comment: You need to change `COUNT` to `SUM` and `ELSE NULL` to `ELSE 0` for this to work, I think.

Comment: @Ken - shouldn't need to - aggregate functions ignore NULLs, COUNT(something) returns the count of non-NULL values.  Have tried it and it works fine.  That said, perhaps SUM with 1 and 0 would be more intuitive.

Comment: @Ken - answer updated to include your suggested change as a decent alternative.

Comment: @Will: Good point. I find the `SUM` more intuitive. I just made the comment and didn't vote down; since you're absolutely right with your first comment, it's a good thing. :)

Comment: @Will: +1 for your answer (especially presenting both options). Nice. :)

Comment: @Will ..thanks for all the suggestions... but I prefer the one given by Michael... there is no case statement.